# Rename workgroup computers from CSV

Tags: powershell, hostname

I'm looking to rename a bunch of remote Workgroup computers by deploying a script and a CSV with old/new hostnames.

The logic would be something like the following and would be executed locally on the computer:
Find hostname in CSV and rename to the new hostname.

This basic Rename-Computer script is close, but I'm not trying to rename multiple domain machines.

```
PS C:\> $a = Import-Csv ServerNames.csv -Header OldName, NewName
PS C:\> Foreach ( $Server in $a ) {Rename-Computer -ComputerName    $Server.OldName -NewName $Server.NewName -DomainCredential Domain01\Admin01 -Force -Restart}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's the expected result ? what's the result you get ? if you post that someone can help

Comment: If I understand the question right, you are trying to run the computer for just the one computer. So could you just filter the spreadsheet on the `ComputerName` environmental variable?  e.g. `Import-Csv ServerNames.csv -Header OldName, NewName | Where-Object {$_.oldname -eq $env:computername} | ForEach-Object {Rename-Computer -NewName $_.NewName -DomainCredential Domain01\Admin01 -Force -Restart}` (note you'll need to be more explicit in creating the credentials otherwise it'll prompt.)

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks BenH! This makes perfect sense.